# Can't find appropriate way to track progress using uploadId in new AWS SDK v3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-js-v3

Here is the code snippet that I use with old AWS SDK v2 in NodeJS.

```
      const partInformation = await this.s3
        .uploadPart({
          Bucket: "BucketName",
          Key: "Object key for which the multipart upload was initiated",
          UploadId: "Upload ID identifying the multipart upload whose part is being uploaded",
          PartNumber: "Part number of part being uploaded. This is a positive integer between 1 and 10,000",
          ContentLength: "Chunk size",
          Body: "Stream"
        })
        .on("httpUploadProgress", evt => {
          console.log(evt);
        })
        .promise();
```

I can track upload progress of multipart upload for each UploadId and PartNumber using this method. What is the exact equivalent of this method in new AWS SDK V3 s3 client? I tried to use UploadPartCommand but can't able to track the progress.

Here is the example that I tried:

```
const client = new S3Client(conf);
await client.send(new UploadPartCommand(params));
```

But can't find a way to track progress here.

Comment: Using UploadPartCommand seems like a good approach, try adding the code that you have tried and that doesn't work, so that others can see what is wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SebastianOscarLopez Added what I have tried so far.